# RSpec do I test both sides of a relationship

Tags: testing, rspec, relationship

lets say I have two models

```rails
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :followings, :through => :friendships, :foreign_key => "followed_id"
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :following, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "followed_id"
end
```

now in my user_spec.rb I have this test

```rails
it "should delete all friendships after user gets destroyed" do
  @user.destroy
  [@friendship].each do |friendship|
    lambda do
      Friendship.find(friendship)
    end.should raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
  end
end
```

is this the right place to test the :dependent => :destroy relation or does this belong inside the friendship_spec.rb or doesn't it matter in which of the two specs I test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using [shoulda_matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) to test your associations:

```
# user_spec.rb
it { should have_many(:friendships).dependent(:destroy) }

# friendship_spec.rb
it { should belong_to(:user) }
```

Having each model test its own associations is the best approach IMHO.

Comment: but these tests only cover the relationship not the mechanism after I delete a parent record, right? They just check, that there is a has many, dependent => destroy in my parent and a belongs_to in my child?

Comment: That is correct, but that is really all you should be testing in your app--otherwise you are testing the Rails code itself, which is out of scope. Rails associations have their own specs and are thoroughly tested.

Comment: so this means I don't test if the child record gets deleted, I just test that I have implemented the functionality to get child records deleted if the parent record is deleted

Comment: Correct. You're trusting that the Rails developers have already tested the implementation of `:dependent => :destroy`.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is sometimes a matter of taste, but I think the spec for `User` is probably the best place to test this. The method you're calling to start the test is a method on `User`, so it makes sense to test it along the other tests for `User` as well.

Comment: and do I test the other side as well, the belongs_to side, or does the first test, which passes, covers that already?